# ruby inject method not doing what I thought it should be doing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Does anyone have any idea why this is failing?

```
ree-1.8.7-2011.03 :008 > 3.times.inject({}) {|result, el| result[el.months.ago.strftime("%B")] = "blah"}
IndexError: string not matched
  from (irb):8:in `[]='
  from (irb):8
  from (irb):8:in `inject'
  from (irb):8:in `each'
  from (irb):8:in `times'
  from (irb):8:in `each'
  from (irb):8:in `
```

Comment: Have you tried simplifying the code to the minimum amount of code required to demonstrate the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`inject`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject) feeds the block's return value into the next iteration as `result` but Hash assignment returns what was assigned. Return `result` from the block:

```
3.times.inject({}) {|result, el| result[el.months.ago.strftime("%B")] = "blah"; result }
```

or use [`each_with_object`](https://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) since you're not really injecting:

```
3.times.each_with_object({}) {|el, result| result[el.months.ago.strftime("%B")] = "blah" }
```

Comment: @patrick: You usually only want `inject` if you're doing something structurally similar to accumulating a total (or if you're in 1.8 without Rails where there is no `each_with_object`). And make sure you note the argument order swap for the block when switching from `inject` to `each_with_object`.

Comment: If you're using 1.8.x and want `each_with_object` (and a huge pile of other 1.9 stuff) then Marc-Andre Lafortune's excellent [backports](https://github.com/marcandre/backports) gem (`[sudo] gem install backports`) provides it.

Comment: no need to use each_with_object, you can write *result.update(key => value)* to update the accumulated hash result.

Answer (score 3):

This probably should be a comment to your question, but it would be pretty unreadable, so here it goes: `Enumerable#inject`/`Enumerable#inject` are overused in the Ruby community. In your case you're injecting to build a hash, but you have [Hash.[]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) for that:

```
Hash[(0...3).map { |x| [x.months.ago.strftime("%B"), "blah"] }]
```

With Facets' [mash](http://rubyworks.github.com/facets/doc/api/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-mash):

```
require 'facets'
(0...3).mash { |x| [x.months.ago.strftime("%B"), "blah"] }
```

With Ruby >= 2.1:

```
(0...3).map { |x| [x.months.ago.strftime("%B"), "blah"] }.to_h
```

Comment: Using #reduce instead of #inject clearly shows if your application of this method makes sense in given problem :)

Comment: @samuil: I don't get what you mean.

Comment: @Andrew: horrible why? would it be better with mash intead of the go-backwards-Hash[]? the +1 was a figure of speech? :-)

Comment: @tokland: I must have got distracted and forgot to upvote. What I don't like is how there's 57 characters between the `[` and `]`.

Comment: @Andrew: Hash[...] is ugly, I totally agree. I (and others) have been preaching for years for mash to be accepted into Ruby's enumerable but Matz is not into it :-( http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/666. Every language (every serious language) has something similar, why Ruby does not?

Comment: @tokland: Can you link to the discussion you've had on it? At the very least, I'd be interested in his view on it.

Comment: @Andrew: see the link to issue 666

Comment: @tokland: when your intention is to "reduce" given collection to something more compact, that's probably good place to use #reduce.

Answer (score 1):

Because the return value of that statement (in the block) is the string, not the hash. Assuming that's what you thought you were doing ;)

I just did the same thing the other day when I wasn't paying attention :/

Answer (score 0):

Please see the first comment here:

http://blog.purepistos.net/index.php/2008/01/03/ruby-string-not-matched/

You need to make sure the return value of each iteration is your hash, as the second time you run it, it's the string you assigned in the first iteration.

Also see here:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject

"each element in the collection will be passed to the named method of memo. In either case, the result becomes the new value for memo."

The specific error message you're seeing is it's trying to apply the [] operator to your string, which is causing the error message.