# Why reduce([]) raise a NoMethodError while trying to push a value to it?

Tags: ruby

The following code works:

```
irb(main):001:0> (0..10).to_a.reduce([]) { |x, y| x.push(y) }
=> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

But this raises NoMethodError:

```
irb(main):002:0> (0..10).to_a.reduce([]) { |x, y| x.push(y) if y.odd? }
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /root/.irb:280:in `<main>'
        4: from (irb):2
        3: from (irb):2:in `reduce'
        2: from (irb):2:in `each'
        1: from (irb):2:in `block in irb_binding'
NoMethodError (undefined method `push' for nil:NilClass)
```

Why is this the case? Should not the later push variable y to array x if y is odd?

Comment: The block you're using with `reduce` should return the container `x`, each time it is executed. But what will the block `{ |x, y| x.push(y) if y.odd? }` return if `y` is not odd?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reduce returns nil on summation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488579/reduce-returns-nil-on-summation)

Comment: Could also duplicate [**ruby inject method not doing what I thought it should be doing**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7802349/479863) but I'm wary of dropping my golden dupe-hammer.

Comment: An aside: you don't need `.to_a`. The class `Range` includes `Enumerable`, the module containing the instance method `reduce`, and has an instance method [Range#each](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Range.html#method-i-each) which returns an enumerator. `reduce`, like all `Enumerable` instance methods, requires that its receiver be an enumerator. When it sees that `(0..10)` is not an enumerator it silently inserts `each` between the range and itself (`(0..10).each.reduce...`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here `reduce` can be used, but you *must* chain properly. The return value of each iteration is sent into the next:

```
(0..10).reduce([ ]) do |x, y|
   x << y if (y.odd?)
   x
end
```

Since this chaining can be annoying as the thing you chain never changes anyway there's an alternative:

```
(0..10).each_with_object([ ]) do |y, x|
   x << y if (y.odd?)
end
```

Where each round `x` is always the "object" being passed in each time and ultimately returned.

Even easier:

```
(0..10).select(&:odd?)
```

Where that just filters to grab all the odd values, no need to pass around a temporary array.

Comment: "no temporary array necessary" - this does create the same number of arrays, though. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev It absolutely does, but at least you don't need to pay attention to that fact.

Comment: _"The return value of each iteration is sent into the next"_ ? I think "The return value of each iteration is sent into accumulator" will sound good, where accumulator default value is [ ]

Comment: @ray The accumulator starts out as the "seed value" which is first element in the array if not specified.

Answer (score 2):

Each iteration of `reduce` should return something. In your current code, when `y` is not odd, that iteration of the `reduce` loop returns `nil`, so on the next iteration `x` is equal to `nil`, which does not have the method `push`, hence the `NoMethodError`.

You can handle this by returning `x` unchanged if `y` is not odd, like so:

```
(0..10).to_a.reduce([]) { |x, y| y.odd? ? x.push(y) : x }
```

With result:

```
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
```